# How to capture python print() form existing code that uses os.fork()?

Tags: python, fork

I am testing/debugging existing python programs (so I'am not allowed to change the existing code) that use `os.fork()` for parallel processing.  When I try to capture the printouts (in a Linux bash shell terminal):

```
python program.py > program.out 2>&1
```

The file `program.out` only contains the printouts from the parent process, nothing at all from any other child processes.

How should we do to capture ALL of the printouts of from ALL processes?

Extra info: All the program's processes are calling the same python function that has a print(), which also prints out os.getpid() for process tracking.  On the terminal without redirection, I see all the outputs with ALL the process pids, while with the redirection, the capture file contains only the outputs with the parent's pid.

Comment: For me that sounds more like a shell/bash question, consider adding these tags to your question.

Comment: @NicoAlbers The shell is out of the loop once the program starts, why do you think it's a shell question?

Comment: When you fork a child process it inherits the original process's `stdout`, so its output should go to the file.

Comment: If you don't redirect the output, do you see the child process's output on the terminal?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I do see all the child processes's output on the terminal.

Comment: I suspect you're running into output buffering issues. Output to terminals is line-buffered, output to files and pipes is fully buffered.